# Precision and Scale of numeric type in sql server express 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, numeric, sqldatatypes

i declared a column as numeric(5,3) in sql server 2008 exp r2 and i assumed that it would allow me to save values like 12345.123 but when i tried to enter anything greater than 100 it gives me overflow error. it made me believe that in numeric(5,3), 5 represents the total length of number including precision and scale. Having this in mind, i changed the type of column to decimal(9,3) and assumed that it would allow me to enter values like 123456.123 but it again gives overflow error. I can't understand how this datatype and its precision and scale is interpreted by sql server.
**Update:**
Strange thing is that when inserting value numeric(9,3) only allows to enter values like 1234.123 but when editing the row i can enter value 123456.123. don't know what's happening here :(

Comment: RE: Update, How are you doing the insert? Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: ah yes i do have trigger on insert. let me check if its the one creating the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decimal(9,3)` should work fine for `123456.123` please recheck!

Executing

```
declare @d decimal(9,3) = 123456.123
```

gives no error. This datatype allows 6 digits to the left of the decimal point and 3 to the right.

Comment: plz see the updated question. is there a chance that i have some issue with installation of sql server. Furthermore, is my assumption, 9 is the sum of precision and scale, correct or is this 9 for scale and 3 for precision ?

Comment: @Muhammad - The issue is far more likely to be in your `INSERT` code or perhaps an insert trigger. Please tell us how you are inserting it and if you have any triggers. [Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)